# ios: Moving images based on orientation

Tags: xcode, ios6, landscape

I am trying to display a set of images in different locations when my app is in landscape vs. portrait mode. I have already searched and found reference to the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration` method, where I added code like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.getStartedImage1.frame = CGRectMake(5, 100, 155, 115);
        self.getStartedImage2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 155, 115);
        self.getStartedImage3.frame = CGRectMake(315, 100, 155, 115);
    }
    else
    {
        self.getStartedImage1.frame = CGRectMake(238, 96, 155, 115);
        self.getStartedImage2.frame = CGRectMake(238, 219, 155, 115);
        self.getStartedImage3.frame = CGRectMake(238, 342, 155, 115);
    }
}
```

This worked great until I realized that if you go to the view while already in landscape mode, the method doesn't run. This makes sense, as I'm opening the view without rotating anything. However, it doesn't help my predicament. So I continued my search and came upon method `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. I added the same body to this method and it is getting called, but perhaps too late because the changes to the image frames are not appearing in the simulator. I have the same problem if I try to move the code to `viewWillAppear`. I have seen some complex solutions involving multiple views, which I'd rather avoid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're fighting with `autolayout`. There are three solutions I can think of.

1. Turn off `autolayout`. If you are already managing all the views frames yourself then this is probably the correct path.
2. Move your layout code to `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`. This is hacky but quick. It also allows `autolayout` to do it's thing *mostly*.
3. Swap out the applicable constraints for rotation. This will be the most work, but arguably the most flexible in the long-run for things like internationalization.

Regarding number three:

Constraints (`NSLayoutConstraint`s) are real objects that can be inspected and edited in both IB and code. Since layouts can be immensely complex, here is a very simple example. Suppose I have two buttons in my view controller's view one above the other (connected to two outlets `buttonOne` and `buttonTwo`), and I want to reverse their position in landscape orientation. Code like this (while inadvisable in this form) does work, and provides an example of how to swap out constraints.

```
@implementation MyAutoViewController {
    NSArray *_portraitConstraints;
    NSArray *_landscapeConstraints;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Clear constraints from Nib. 
    // PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS PART IN REAL LIFE
    NSArray *current = self.view.constraints;
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *contsra in current) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:contsra];
    }

    // Set up views dictionary
    UIButton *buttonOne = self.buttonOne;
    UIButton *buttonTwo = self.buttonTwo;
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(buttonOne, buttonTwo);

    // Set distance from left to both buttons to standard space
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[buttonOne]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[buttonTwo]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

    // HERE IS WHERE IT GETS INTERESTING
    // ### Create portrait constraints ###
    _portraitConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[buttonOne]-[buttonTwo]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];

    // ### Create landscape constraints ###
    _landscapeConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[buttonTwo]-[buttonOne]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];

    // Add the appropriate constraints
    [self.view addConstraints:(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))?_portraitConstraints:_landscapeConstraints];

}
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        [self.view removeConstraints:_landscapeConstraints];
        [self.view addConstraints:_portraitConstraints];
    } else {
        [self.view removeConstraints:_portraitConstraints];
        [self.view addConstraints:_landscapeConstraints];
    }
}
```

I really suggest watching the three videos on `autolayout` from the WWDC2012. `Autolayout` is a lot to get the head around.

Comment: Thanks. I went with #2 for now. I can't turn off auto layout since it's essential for my other views, and I'm not sure I fully understand #3. Do you mean just remove the constraints for the images in question?

Comment: @CherylYaeger I added some more information in regards to option 3.

Comment: Thanks for adding this extra info!